# Is it possible to check external battery with Android SDK?

Tags: android

I would like to create an android app that checks the external battery state (charge via micro USB).

I have checked the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html), [UsbAccessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html) and [UsbManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html) classes 
it seems non functional.

So any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: I won't say Battery Manager is non functional, it's actually pretty handy , in case, you are trying to find out the condition of your device's internal battery , but it does not help you with the external battery .

Comment: you should try ADK may got some break through

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Android SDK is ADK. Maybe you meant NDK.

Comment: I am talking about ADK(Accessory Development Kit) not SDK. Visit http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

Comment: Thanks Biraj Zalavadia,i have a look on this now.

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible unless the external battery has a charge reporting mechanism.  Even if the phone could measure the USB voltage, most external battery devices have a boost converter to keep on providing 5.0 volts out until the internal cell is "dead" (or preferably, hits a low voltage cutoff intended to protect its ability to recharge well).

Answer (score 4):

As far as the phone is concerned, an external battery is just a power source like a normal charger. There is no communication; in fact these external batteries short-circuit the two data pins of the USB port to signal their prescence. Since they also contain circuitry to produce constant 5v output voltage the phone has not even a theoretical chance of knowing the battery state. I'm sorry but you are fighting a losing battle here, you will only be able to tell whether the phone is still receiving sufficient power from the external battery or not.